# Making a drag image opaque instead of semi-transparent

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, opacity, alpha

I would like the drag image in my application to be opaque (solid) instead of semi-transparent, so is there a way to specify the image's opacity and alpha level?

I've given my `TransferHandler.setDragImage` an image that was not created with opacity, so I am under the impression that this is default functionality provided by Java. I want the image to be opaque, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the visual representation of he TransferHandler to null.

> "getVisualRepresentation: 
>   public Icon getVisualRepresentation(Transferable t): 
>   Returns an object that establishes the look of a transfer. This is useful for both providing feedback while performing a drag operation and for representing the transfer in a clipboard implementation that has a visual appearance.... The default Swing logic will not do an alpha blended drag animation if the return is null."

http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs7/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#getVisualRepresentation(java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable)

Comment: Thanks for the response and I'll have to look into it a little more.  I did see that function earlier but I didn't think it applied to this situation.  At any rate, I created a subclass of TransferHandler where this is overridden to return null and for some reason the function is never called.  Like I said, I still need to look into it because I must be missing something.

Comment: Yea I myself am not familiar with this class, just told you what I could find on the internet. If you really need this to work, the you can just manually draw the image in the JFrame.